# WordPress: Single query for multiple post types w/ meta_queries?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to set up a query in WordPress returning combined results from different post types, with meta_queries that apply to each. In this case, I'm looking to get standard posts with a corresponding `meta_query` (custom field) of `'related_'.$post_type'`, and posts of an `event` custom post type *after* the current date. My query is as follows, and while it seems to get the standard posts properly, it's showing all events, not just upcoming ones:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => array('post', 'event'),
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page'    =>  $limit,
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'related_'.$post_type,
                    'value' => $post_id,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'event_start_date',
                    'type'    => 'DATE',
                    'value'   => current_time('Ymd'),
                    'compare' => '>=',
                ),
            )
        );
```

Is this possible to do in a single query, or would I need to do separate queries for posts and events, with the respective meta_queries, and combine the resulting arrays? Or can I better organize the query to align each meta_query with its respective post type? Thanks for any assistance here.

Answer (score 1):

You can query multiple post types:

```
post_type (string / array) - use post types. Retrieves posts by Post Types, default value is 'post'. If 'tax_query' is set for a query, the default value becomes 'any';
```

Edit: I have a feeling that you should be using the `YYYY-MM-DD` mysql date format, but you're right - the [`current_time()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) does accept PHP date formats like `Ymd` (as well as `'mysql'` or `'timestamp'`).

The structure of the query seems fine - the only thing that looks strange to me is the value of your 'related_'.$post_type custom field:

```
'key' => 'related_'.$post_type,
'value' => $post_id,
```

Is the post_id actually the value of the custom field? The postmeta table is made up of:

```
meta_id
post_id
meta_key
meta_value
```

The post_id isn't usually the meta_value as well?

Comment: thanks for the response- interestingly, I use the same meta_query for the actual events page, i.e. showing events only after the current date, and it works fine; it seems here the issue is using it in combination with querying the other posts (?)

Comment: Sorry - it looks like you're use of current_time() is correct. So the only thing that stands out to me is your use of the post_id as the meta_value - I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. When applying the `meta_query` argument to a query with multiple `post_types`, the `meta_query` arguments are applied to all post types and therefore, it returns only the posts that contain the meta fields that are queried.

For example, when executing a `wp_query` with the following `meta_query` arguments:

```
'meta_query' => array(
   array(
      'key' => 'agenda_date',
      'value' => date('Ymd'),
      'compare' => '>=',
   ),
)
```

Only the posts of the `post_type` that contain the meta field 'agenda_date' are returned. All other posts are ignored.

If I remove the `meta_query` arguments, all works well and I can query multiple post types (`'post_type' => 'agenda,post'`) without a problem.

Fiddling around with `relation` settings and simulating fake `meta_query` arguments doesn't seem to work, so the only solution would be to hijack the SQL query itself and to modify the `JOIN` and `WHERE` statements of the query.

Too bad though.